# Can I change the "range" punctuation in siunitx?

Tags: punctuation, siunitx

When using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), by default, `\SIrange{0}{10}{\celsius}` will render `0 °C to 10 °C`.

Is there any general way to change the default rendering of ranges to `0--10 °C` (i.e., using an en dash instead of "to").

Comment: Its is not recommended to change this setting according to the siunitx documentation: Physical quantities could be misinterpret as negative values if written in
this way. As the quantity is a single mathematical entity, writing the values with an
en-dash followed by a single unit is also incorrect. As a result, using the word ‘to’ is
strongly recommended.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The relevant option is `range-phrase`. This is explained in section [4.6 Lists, products and ranges](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=33) of the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{range-phrase=\,--\,}  
\SIrange{0}{10}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, dunno how I skipped over that! While we're on the subject, is there a way to eliminate the first `°C` after generating the `0 °C--10 °C` in order to render `0--10 °C`? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `range-units=single`

Comment: If you want to apply this to individual instances of `\SIrange`, you can also use `\SIrange[range-phrase=--]{0}{10}{\celsius}` instead of `\sisetup`, which applies globally.

Comment: It is better to add a small non-breaking space before and after the dash. Source: [Forssman u. de Jong: Detailtypografie](https://typografie.de/produkt/detailtypografie/)

Comment: @Jake: Because of the reasons given by @mab0189 in the comment of the question they changed the behaviour so `range-units=single` will return `(2 to 4)
°C` as of 2024