# Siunitx: formatting range

Tags: formatting, packages, siunitx, number, numrange

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43657/can-i-change-the-range-punctuation-in-siunitx), I obtain

```
\sisetup{
  range-phrase=—
}
\SIrange{40}{50}{\liter}
```

> 40 L—50 L

Is there a way that can give me output in this format?

> 40—50 L

Comment: Off-topic: `\SIrange` is somewhat deprecated; you should use `\qtyrange` unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated in the last three years or so.

Comment: Yes, the reference is quite old. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have access to a reasonably recent version of the `siunitx` package, I suggest you try

```
\qtyrange[range-units=single]{10}{50}{\liter}
```

Of course, the `range-phrase=\textendash` and `range-units=single` options may both be set as part of an `\sisetup` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=\textendash, range-units=single}

\begin{document}
\qtyrange{10}{50}{\liter}
\end{document}
```